Application Works on All Devices Except Samsung S24 Ultra: How to Check ANR Logs on Crashlytics?
I've developed an Android application that performs well on a variety of devices, but I've encountered an issue specifically with the Samsung S24 Ultra. On this device, the application exhibits unexpected behaviour it gives an ANR with close app or wait and getting nothing in logs. I've thoroughly tested the app on multiple devices, and this problem seems to be unique to the Samsung S24 Ultra.
To diagnose the issue, I'd like to check the ANR (Application Not Responding) logs on Crashlytics as application is live on Playstore. However, I'm unsure about the steps to retrieve ANR logs specifically on Crashlytics.
FYI- The application is working fine with Android 14 tested on various devices (Samsung S23 Ultra)
Could someone provide guidance on how to access ANR logs on Crashlytics?
Additionally, has anyone else experienced compatibility issues with the Samsung S24 Ultra or encountered similar challenges with latest devices?
Any insights, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!
Please guide on checking the ANR Logs on crashlytics and if anything specifc needs to be done for Samsung S24 Ultra.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
